# How to get Captured Image Path and Name in Android?

Tags: android, image, imageview, image-uploading, image-capture

i am creating one application in which i want to upload image. before uploading i have to select image or capture it. if i am selecting an image from gallery then i can successfully upload image but when i am trying to upload captured image then captured image path not found so please help me to solve my problem

```
capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stubIntent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        Intent cameraIntent = new  Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imgUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
    }
});
```

OnActivity Result Code

```
if(requestCode==2)
{
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");    
    pic.setImageBitmap(photo);

    String name=(String) data.getExtras().get("data"); 

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //  Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mCapturedImageURI,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

            String picpath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but after applying above code Exception is execute. it dont work

Comment: what exception did you get.

Comment: i wrote above code in try catch so Exception e execute.                                 catch (Exception e) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

Answer (score 0):

Below code will open camera -

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Below code will be executed when you have clicked picture-

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
            if (data != null) {
                Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
                byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", ba1));

                try {

                    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://..../uploadPic.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.i("Excecption", "caught in exception");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Excecption", "caught in exception");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        // We need to recycle unused bitmaps
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

Comment: thanks bro but your code dont give me the exact path of the Captured Image.

Comment: it doesn't give the path, it will upload it to your server as soon as you click on ok